# Passing data from php to MATLAB

Tags: php, mysql, matlab

i have php project using mysql database
my question is how to pass data from php(data retrieve from mysql database) to MATLAB program
is there any tool for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use PHP. You can issue SQL statements to import data into the MATLAB workspace using the [Database Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/run-sql-query.html).

Example:

```
logintimeout(5)
conn = database('dbtoolboxdemo', 'username', 'password')
curs = exec(conn, 'select productNumber, productDescription from productTable')

>> curs =
      Attributes: []
            Data: {10x1 cell}
  DatabaseObject: [1x1 database]
        RowLimit: 0
        SQLQuery: 'select productdescription from producttable'
         Message: []
            Type: 'Database Cursor Object'
       ResultSet: [1x1 sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet]
          Cursor: [1x1 com.mathworks.toolbox.database.sqlExec]
       Statement: [1x1 sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement]
           Fetch: [1x1 com.mathworks.toolbox.database.fetchTheData]

close(curs)
close(conn)
```